# Chrome Driver Error using Selenium and NUnit Console: Unable to Discover Open Pages

Tags: selenium, nunit, selenium-chromedriver, cruisecontrol.net

All of my Selenium tests are getting failed only when running it through Cruisecontrol.net, whereas running it through command line using the same user (on which cc.net runs) seems fine.

Running on cc.net is also resulting in opening up more than 30~40 chromedriver processes and which eventually is resulting in "Unable to Discover Open Pages".
Running on a commandline is fine and has only 1 chromedriver process.

So far I have tried :
--no-sandbox option,
Power settings changes on that user,
Updated Chromedriver to latest version &
restarted and rebooted the cc.net service and server

Any help is highly appreciated....

Comment: Just to confirm, is CruiseControl.net running as a windows service when it fails?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues in the past running some tasks via CCNet, those tasks are typically ones which require the creation of a `window` in the context of MS windows.

That means any process, or child process, which tries to create a new (visible) window may misbehave. Console windows appear to be fine as they share a common instance (maybe?). From experience and testing this is a MS windows 'issue' not localised to CCNet.

I've encountered this with selenium as it's typically driving a browser (which itself - attempts to - show a window). I *have* had success with `PhantomJs` driven via selenium in CCNet (when running as a limited service)

If the windows service is set to run as `SYSTEM` then you can allow the service to "interact with the desktop". This allows the service to create new windows under the service account. However in my experience this has only worked when a user session is attached*; disconnecting from the session returns to the non-working behaviour.

`*` This is when windows prompts the user to connect to the `SYSTEM` service window station to see the interactive content (the windows). It may be only supported on windows server, and I think I saw it only when connecting via Remote Desktop to the server.

I couldn't find an elegant solution to this problem, beyond invoking the process via `PSEXEC` onto a server/session which behaved as expected and consistently.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue with `MSTest` and `Microsoft Test Agents` and below is the solution for how I managed to fix it. However, I don't know `CruiseControl`, so I have no idea if you can install it to run as a process.

Basically the Test Agent was installed as a service, and every process launched from a Windows (NT) Service runs on Session 0, invisible to a logged on user.

Chrome is trying to move away from Session 0 and you can find further references of this here (comment 21 in the link below, but actually the whole thread is a good read in respect to this subject): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396#c21

Now, to fix this, there are several options available: Download a Canary build from Chrome but this is not recommended as this is only a temporary fix. Chrome devs are saying that in the near future Session 0 will no longer be available with Chrome (and ChromeDriver).

The best solution is to have MS Test Agent installed as a process so that all applications are visible to the logged in user. More details can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx

Another option for this is to have the settings below added as Chrome arguments, however I didn't test with those using the Test Agent as a Windows Service, so I don't know if it's working or not, but I can confirm that it's working with the Test Agent as a process.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

As for the multiple instances of `ChromeDriver` open, again the issue was for MSTest, so maybe `NUnit` is different, but my issue was that the tests were failing in the `TestInitialize` method. When this happens, `TestCleanup` is no longer called. It seems that `TestCleanup` gets executed only when `TestMethod` fails and having my `driver.Quit();` statement in `TestCleanup` I ended with the memory depleted on the test server because of the number of `ChromeDriver` instances open.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin, your analysis on Session 0 & 1 seems logical in this situation.
So far they seems to be working fine after I downgraded Chrome Browser and chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. The (ugly) workaround I set up was :

- open a session on the CI Server
- run the `ChromeDriver.exe` from the command line
- leave the session open

Now selenium webdriver can connect to the `chromedriver` listening on its specific port and having a graphic session to interact with.